# stream_set_chunk_size(): The chunk size cannot be larger than 2147483647 in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to install [Craftable](https://getcraftable.com/docs/6.0/installation)  and when I run `php artisan craftable:install` command it throws the error:

> In StreamHandler.php line 144: stream_set_chunk_size(): The chunk size
> cannot be larger than 2147483647

Please help me out to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

A temporary solution would be going to your config/database.php and change the charset and collation from utf8mb4 to utf8.

```
'charset' => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
```

This happens because utf8mb4 uses 4 bytes per character, and the email column has a 255 character length which is greater than the limit 767 bytes. 255 x 4bytes = 1020b.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem while performing `php artisan migration` command & It resolved by correcting the memory_limit parameter in Xampp php.ini file.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a more generic answer, one can not assume that XAMPP was used here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change memory_limit in php.in file XAMPP . I can solved same problem.